# Understanding different variants of declaring a task in Gradle

Tags: android-studio, gradle, task, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

There are two different variants of declaring a task in Gradle.

1.

```
task myTask() {}
```

2.

```
task task3 << {}
```

To test how they behave, I´ve created a sample android project

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.android.gradletest"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
}



task task1() {
    println "Task 1"
}

task task2() {
    println "Task 2"
}

task task3 << {
    println "Task 3"
}

task task4() {
    println "Task 4"
}
```

**First attempt** was executing Task 1

```
Task 1
Task 2
Task 4
:app:task1 UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 6.462 secs

Process finished with exit code 0
```

As you see, not just only Task 1 is executed, but the complete build WITHOUT Task 3.

**Second attempt** was running Task 3 directly:

```
Task 1
Task 2
Task 4
:app:task3
Task 3

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 6.577 secs

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Result was again, the complete build seems to be triggered, but this time WITH Task 3 at the end.

**Third attempt** was simply building the complete project by pressing the run button of Android Studio

```
Task 1
Task 2
Task 4
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72211Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42211Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJava
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources
:app:preDexDebug
:app:dexDebug
:app:validateDebugSigning
:app:packageDebug
:app:zipalignDebug
:app:assembleDebug
Information:BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

As you can see, everything gets triggered, except Task 3!

Now I have two questions:

1. What is the << task declaration ment for, when we aren´t able to run it standalone and it is not triggered within the build process?
2. Why is it triggering multiple tasks when I execute just one out of the Task Menu and how do I execute just a single one then?
   [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle build goes through 3 phases:

1. **Initialization** - determine which projects are going to take part in the build, and creates a Project instance for each of these projects.
2. **Configuration** - configure project objects and specifically the tasks to be executed.
3. **Execution** - executing the subset of the tasks created and configured during the configuration phase.

Now, a task definition contains 3 stages:

```
task myTask {
    // Configuration scope
    // will be executed during the configuration phase

    doFirst {
        // Will be executed during the execution phase before the task defined behavior
    }

    doLast {
        // Will be executed during the execution phase after the task defined behavior
    } 
}
```

So, when you define a task like this:

```
task task1() {
    println "Task 1"
}
```

Since the `println` statement is part of the configuration scope it will be executed in the configuration phase, regardless if this task was chosen to execute or not.

Now, using the `<<` operator for defining a task is actually a shortcut for defining the `doLast` closure for the task, i.e.

```
task task3 << {
    println "Task 3"
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
task task3 {
    doLast {
        println "Task 3"
    }
}
```

Then, per my explanation above, in this case the `println` statement will only be executed during the execution phase, in case `task3` has to be executed as was determined during the configuration phase.

If you're interested to learn more about it I would highly recommend you to go through the following sections in Gradle user guide:

1. [Build Script Basics](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html)
2. [The Build Lifecycle](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html)